# mixed tense in sentence

Tags: tense-agreement

> Giesbrecht **`says`** she **`had to`** tell the event organizer she
>   **`will have to`** cancel unless another arrangement **`can`** be worked out. (Flu shot rule could cancel youth choir's concert at
>   seniors' home - CBC new Dec.1 2014)

I am wondering if I could replace 'will have to' with 'would have to' and "can' with "could' without changing its intended meaning?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the present forms *will* and *can* with the past forms *would* and *could* ***might*** change the meaning.

The past form *had* (*had to tell*) indicates that the choir director's conversation with the event organizer took place at some time before she spoke to the press.

The present forms, with the present form *says*, indicate that at the time of writing any cancellation or alternative arrangement lay in the future: the event had not yet been cancelled.

The past forms *would* and *could* would not exclude this reading; but they would also accommodate a situation in which cancellation or rescheduling did take place, after the conversation took place but before the director spoke to the press and the story was written.